# JQuery Ascensor JS Plugin Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a single-page scrolling website leveraging the Ascensor JQuery plugin, and am having a lot of trouble getting it setup correctly. The documentation at http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/ is helpful, but I still must be missing something. What I want is a simple 3-floor layout, top to bottom. It seems that the layout of my "building" gets generated correctly, but I am unable to move between the "levels." The arrow keys and my links don't move the page at all. Can I get a little help with my code? Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks, 
Brett

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Ascensor Test</title>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ascensor.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#house').ascensor(
    {
        AscensorName:'ascensor',
        ChildType:'div',
        AscensorFloorName:'Home | Implementation | HTML',
        Time:1000,
        Easing:'easeInOutCubic',
        WindowsOn:1,
        Direction:'y',
        AscensorMap:'1|1 & 2|1 & 3|1',
        KeyNavigation: true,
        Queued:false,
        QueuedDirection:"x"
    });
});
</script>

<style>
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#house
{
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

#navigation
{
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}

#ascensorFloor1
{
    background-color: orange;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="navigation">
        <a href="#" class="ascensorLink ascensorLink1">Floor 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="ascensorLink ascensorLink2">Floor 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="ascensorLink ascensorLink3">Floor 3</a>
    </div>

    <div id="house">
        <div>
            Floor 1
        </div>
        <div>
            Floor 2
        </div>
        <div>
            Floor 3
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe the `<div>` tags of your Floors need corresponding ID's. i.e. `ascensorFloor1`.

Comment: Hi @UwConcept, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that didn't seem to help. I added IDs to my divs, like ascensorFloor1, ascensorFloor2, ascensorFloor3, etc, but the behavior is the same. Still no moving levels. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not you, it is in "jquery-1.9.1.js".
I've tried to implement ascensor myself, and figured that the problem is that the plugin doesn't work with the last update from jQuery. The version originaly used 1.5.1. Check it out the jQuery in Git (https://github.com/seekvence/ascensor).
I've tried to find out why, but see no reason for that! Even tried to use the jQuery migrate plugin, but it didn't work as well!

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone. I emailed the developer of Ascensor, and he said the same thing as @user2286414. The plugin doesn't yet work with JQuery 1.9, but he is looking to update it soon. Using JQuery 1.8.3 instead fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the IDs, since it is the plugin that is generating them. So you shoudn't put them in your mark-up in the first place. I had the same problem as you and after going through a lot "on/off switching stuff", i found out that the problem was in the key navigation declaration. If you turn it to false, it starts working. Don't ask me why, but "KeyNavigation:false" gets the plugin to work. Which is a shame, since key navigation is one of the things i liked about the plugin... Anyway, try this and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Easing:'easeInOutCubic' - don't work

Delete: Easing:'easeInOutCubic',

or: Easing:'linear',
..))

Comment: I am now having trouble getting the easing working. The only one that works for me is linear, the others break the transitions all together. Anyone have any clues?

Comment: I found out that I needed to include the easing plugin. After that, the different easing options worked like a charm. I thought I had tried that before, but I guess not. Working now!